# How to return a value from try, catch, and finally?

Tags: java, exception, double, try-catch, return-value

So when I do a code of blocks inside a `try{}`, and I try to `return` a value, it tells me

> no return values

```
import org.w3c.dom.ranges.RangeException;


public class Pg257E5 
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println(add(args));
    }
    catch(RangeException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("Thanks for using the program kiddo!");
    }
}
public static double add(String[] values)
// shows a commpile error here that I don't have a return value
{
    try
    {
        int length = values.length;
        double arrayValues[] = new double[length];
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
        {
            arrayValues[i] = Double.parseDouble(values[i]);
            sum += arrayValues[i];
        }
        return sum; // I do have a return value here.
        // Is it because if the an exception occurs the codes in try stops and doesn't get to the return value?
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(RangeException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the program!");
        //so would I need to put a return value of type double here?
    }

}
}
```

My question is, how do you return a value when you are using `try` and `catch`?

Comment: You don't need the `RangeException` catch block.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To return a value when using `try/catch` you can use a temporary variable, e.g.

```
public static double add(String[] values) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    try {
        int length = values.length;
        double arrayValues[] = new double[length];
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            arrayValues[i] = Double.parseDouble(values[i]);
            sum += arrayValues[i];
        }
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(RangeException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the program!");
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Else you need to have a return in every execution path (try block or catch block) that has no `throw`.

Comment: What if I do not want a valid value to be returned? Is it a bad practice to return null? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: @JeffHu: Returning null is not always the best solution. In Java throwing an Exception is more often the appropriate way to handle exceptional conditions.

Comment: I would return in finally block, so it happens no matter what.

Comment: @JeffHu Uwe is quite right, though I would add that throwing exceptions is meant for situations in which the application execution has become unrecoverable. I'd argue it's oftentimes better to return 'result' objects, that informs the caller of the outcome of an operation - herein included the result itself or an error message. At any rate returning null should be avoided, if possible/practical.

Answer (score 4):

It is because you are in a `try` statement. Since there *could* be an error, sum *might* not get initialized, so put your return statement in the `finally` block, that way it will for sure be returned.

Make sure that you initialize sum outside the `try/catch/finally` so that it is in scope.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another example that return's a boolean value using try/catch.

```
private boolean doSomeThing(int index){
    try {
        if(index%2==0) 
            return true; 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }finally {
        System.out.println("Finally!!! ;) ");
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is what happens when you get `NumberFormatexception` thrown? You print it and return nothing.

Note: You don't need to catch and throw an Exception back. Usually it is done to wrap it or print stack trace and ignore for example.

```
catch(RangeException e) {
     throw e;
}
```