# NoSuchElementException with Scanner in try/catch block

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

For a simple maze game with two possible game modes I am trying to implement a scanner at the beginning of the game, after using a scanner to ask for the player's name. I decided to make a class `MenuParser`, in which I would like to use static methods which accept objects and pass them through to their respective methods.

For one reason or another, Java keeps on returning the same error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)     at
>   game.MenuParser.startUpMenu(MenuParser.java:26)   at
>   game.MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:18)

I've looked at similar questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405714/java-how-do-you-return-a-value-from-try-catch-and-finally) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398703/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception) ) on how to deal with returning a value from a try/catch block and on what causes `NoSuchElementException` with `Scanner`, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried to move my `return` around, together with simplifying the `Scanner` (e.g. by simply removing the try/catch block), but neither solves the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The main method looks as follows:

```
package game;

import world.Maze;

public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Initialize objects concerned with playing the game
        Player myPlayer = new Player();
        Maze myMaze = new Maze();

        // Print welcome message and ask the player for his/her name
        System.out.println("Hi there! Welcome to this maze game in Java by MV. \n");
        myPlayer.setPlayerNameWithScanner();

        // Ask the player which game mode he/she would like to play: single player or multiplayer?
        int choice = MenuParser.startUpMenu();
        System.out.println(choice);
        // Parse input and depending on the answer initialize the corresponding menu to start the game
    }

}
```

The MenuParser class looks as follows:

```
package game;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MenuParser {

    public static void pause() {

        System.out.println("Please hit enter to continue.");
        Scanner hitEnter = new Scanner(System.in);
        hitEnter.nextLine();
        hitEnter.close();
    }

    public static int startUpMenu() {

        int choice = 0;

        System.out.println("Which game mode would you like to play?" + "\n");
        System.out.println("\t 1. Single player.");
        System.out.println("\t 2. Robot.");

        try(Scanner startUp = new Scanner(System.in)){

            choice = startUp.nextInt();
            System.out.println(choice);

            if(choice != 1 || choice != 2) {

                System.out.println("Sorry, this is not a valid choice.");
                startUpMenu();
            }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException im) {

            System.out.println("Sorry, it seems the input is of wrong type.");
            startUpMenu();
        }
        return choice;
    }
}
```

The Player class looks as follows:

```
package game;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {

    private String playerName;
    private int playerStepScore;

    public Player () {
    }

    public void setPlayerNameWithScanner(){

        System.out.println("Please enter your name. \n");

        try(Scanner playerNameScanner = new Scanner(System.in);){

            String playerName = playerNameScanner.nextLine();
            setPlayerName(playerName);
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException im) {
            System.out.println("Input seems to be wrong");
            setPlayerNameWithScanner();
        }
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }
    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }
    public int getPlayerStepScore() {
        return playerStepScore;
    }
    public void setPlayerStepScore(int playerStepScore) {
        this.playerStepScore = playerStepScore;
    }


}
```

The previous main method (which used multiple scanners, including try-with-recources, without any errors or exceptions) looks as follows:

```
package game;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import game.Cell;
import game.Maze;
import game.Border;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * General variables that will be used throughout the loops
         * that follow; maxXCoor and maxYCoor are used as maximum values
         * to initialize a grid of a certain size; myMaze is a Maze object
         * which is needed to access its methods throughout the loops.
         */
        int maxXCoor = 0;
        int maxYCoor = 0;
        Maze myMaze = new Maze();

        /*
         * A Scanner is invoked to simply deal with the entry
         * of the file name; this location is then saved in the
         * variable fileName, which is then passed onto the next
         * Scanner and FileReader.
         */
        System.out.println("Please enter a file name");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();
        System.out.println(fileName);

        /*
         * This first block is used to scan the entire input file
         * and look for maxXCoor and maxYCoor to initialize the grid.
         */
        try(Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));){

            int count = 1;
            while(input.hasNextLine()) {

                /*
                 * Every line is read as a String which is then 
                 * split using a comma as the delimiter. Every
                 * part that is delimited by a comma is then put into an
                 * array called words.
                 */
                String line = input.nextLine();
                String[] words = line.split(",");

                /*
                 * Basic sanity check to make sure the input file uses
                 * the template which was agreed upon, where the first line
                 * are just headers.
                 */
                if(count == 1) {

                    if(!(words[0].toLowerCase()).equals("xcoordinate")) {

                        System.out.println("It looks like there is an issue with the template of your input file.");
                        System.out.println("Please check your input file and try again!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
                /*
                 * Once we're not at line one anymore, we can start checking
                 * the current coordinates, xCoor and yCoor, against
                 * the maximum coordinates, maxXCoor and maxYCoor.
                 */
                else {

                    int xCoor = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
                    int yCoor = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);

                    if(xCoor > maxXCoor) {

                        maxXCoor = xCoor;
                    }
                    if(yCoor > maxYCoor) {

                        maxYCoor = yCoor;
                    }
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fe) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        /*
         * As Java uses zero-indexing, we will want to
         * augment the values of our maximum coordinates
         * by one, to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions in
         * the future. After that we initialize a 2D array
         * of type Cell with these coordinates.
         */
        maxXCoor++;
        maxYCoor++;
        Cell[][] myGrid = new Cell[maxXCoor][maxYCoor];


        try(Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));){

            int count = 1;
            while(input.hasNextLine()) {

                String line = input.nextLine();
                String[] words = line.split(",");

                if(count > 1) {

                    int xCoor = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
                    int yCoor = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                    Border borderNorth = new Border(words[2]);
                    Border borderSouth = new Border(words[3]);
                    Border borderEast = new Border(words[4]);
                    Border borderWest = new Border(words[5]);
                    Cell myCell = new Cell(borderNorth,borderSouth,borderEast,borderWest);
                    myGrid[xCoor][yCoor] = myCell;

                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fe) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for(int x = maxXCoor-1; x >= 0; x--) {
            // Draw north & south wall
            for(int y = 0; y < maxYCoor; y++) {
                Border myBorderNorth = myGrid[x][y].getNorthWall();
                String myTypeNorth = myBorderNorth.getType();
                if(myTypeNorth.equals("wall")) {
                    System.out.print("+---");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("+   ");
                }
                if(y == maxYCoor-1) {
                    System.out.println("+");
                }
            }
            // Draw west & east wall
            for(int y = 0; y < maxYCoor; y++) {
                Border myBorderWest = myGrid[x][y].getWestWall();
                String myTypeWest = myBorderWest.getType();
                if(myTypeWest.equals("wall")) {
                    System.out.print("|   ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("    ");
                }
                // Draw last eastern wall
                if(y == maxYCoor-1) {
                    System.out.println("|");                    
                }
            }
            // Draw last southern wall
            if(x == 0) {
                for(int y = 0; y < maxYCoor; y++) {
                    System.out.print("+---");
                }
                System.out.println("+");
            }
        }
        myMaze.setGrid(myGrid);
    }

}
```

Comment: can u put "Scanner startUp = new Scanner(System.in)" this inside the try block {} and fyi this line is always true if(choice != 1 || choice != 2)

Comment: Are you actually entering a number when you get asked for input?

Comment: Can we see the `setPlayerNameWithScanner` method?

Comment: @AlperFıratKaya I've tried to initialize it in the try block (instead of using a try with resources) but the error remained.

Thanks for the tip concerning the if-statement. To me this seemed the way to use an `unless ... OR unless ...` but I might be missing something...

Comment: @JacobB. The exception is thrown before I even get to entering a number, so unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: @DM My apologies, I should've posted the whole thing immediately, but I wanted to avoid posting too much code to read through. I'll add it in a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this code:

```
        try(Scanner startUp = new Scanner(System.in)){
            //stuff
        }
```

This is known as a try-with-resources.  The code will automatically close the Scanner when this try block is finished executing.

But once you close a Scanner associated with `System.in`, then `System.in` stays closed.  You get a `NoSuchElementException` if you try to read anything else, even if you use a new `Scanner` .  That seems to be what is happening here.  Most likely, `setPlayerNameWithScanner` is closing a Scanner in a similar manner, causing your problem.

Comment: 'It stays closed' meaning `System.in`.

Comment: @DM I've added more code into my original question. I am indeed using a try-with-resources in my Player class to initialize the player's name. The reason as to why I'm so puzzled, is that I was using multiple Scanners (one 'normal' one which was closed after using it and 2 try-with-resource Scanners) in my original Main method, which worked perfectly fine without any errors or exceptions. Could you perhaps explain why it worked in that case, but it fails to work now?

Comment: @milanv I do not know, especially without seeing the code.

Comment: @DM I posted the code in my original question (under 'the previous main method...') at the end.

Comment: @milanv That code has multiple Scanners, but only one is associated with `System.in`.  The other ones are associated with files.  So they don't conflict with each other.

Comment: Is using multiple scanners across your program (without closing them) bad practice, or does that not matter that much with a small program?

Comment: @milanv Closing the file scanners is a good practice; your system only has so many file handles.  But having two or three file scanners open is not exactly going to break your system.  Don't close the `System.in` scanner unless you are sure you are done with it.

Comment: @DM Thanks! I might try to experiment by simply using one scanner that is initialized in the Main and then passed around to all methods that need it (as I use it a lot to let the player browse through the menu’s with different options).